# eclipse hibernate code generation - custom attribute in .hbm.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping, reverse-engineering

I am using Eclipse hibernate code generation tool `Hibernate Tools 3.4.0.CR1`. The reverse engineering tool generates the .hbm.xml files in the following format

```
    <many-to-one name="ride" class="com.myworkspace.Ride" fetch="select">
        ...
    </many-to-one>
```

What I need is

```
    <many-to-one name="ride" class="com.myworkspace.Ride" fetch="select" lazy="false">
        ...
    </many-to-one>
```

How do I add an extra attribute `lazy="false"` to all my .hbm.xml files having many-to-one relationships?

I have tried adding an attribute in the reverse engineering XML file used by hibernate code generator, which has not been successful, as the attribute `"lazy"` is not allowed as per XML spec. Are there any other ways to do this?

```
<hibernate-reverse-engineering>
    <table name="ride">
        <foreign-key constraint-name="fk_b_ride">
            <many-to-one lazy="false ">
            </many-to-one>
        </foreign-key>
    </table>
</hibernate-reverse-engineering>
```